# How to serialize multiple objects into a json array in Django?

Tags: json, django, serialization

I know how to serialize a single object and then convert it into a json. But I want serialize multiple objects of model (using the serializer) and build a response that contains a json object array?

Is there a direct way of doing it? Or is there a way to make a json array with multiple json objects?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer..

```
from django.core import serializers
serializers.serialize('json', YourModel.objects.filter(attr='foo'), fields=('field1', 'field2'))
```

or if you wish you can bind your serialized objects into a variable like

```
    serialized_data = serializers.serialize('json', YourModel.objects.filter(attr='foo'), fields=('field1', 'field2'))
```

then do what you want.

Comment: I'm not retrieving my objects as a query set. They're in a list. How do I go about it now?